# AWS Sagemaker 'EndpointConnectionError' error related to 'region' when using Amazon Kendra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-regions, amazon-kendra

I'm trying to build a semantic search engine using Amazon Kendra. I wrote the code on Sagemaker's Jupyter Notebook. I'm stuck at the following part:

**Code:**

```
response = kendra.query(
    QueryText = "retrieve blue colored shoes from the inventory data",
    IndexId = "xxxxxx"
)
```

**Error:**

```
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://kendra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

My S3 buckets in which I've stored the datasets used in the code have the 'AWS Region' as 'Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1'. My Amazon Kendra index too has the same region. Then why is my error talking about some other region: eu-north-1?

Answer (score 4):

Try to initialize session and pass the region, then from that session initialize the kendra client:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(region_name="")
kendra_client = session.client('kendra')
kendra_query = ""

kendra_kwargs = {
    "IndexId": KENDRA_INDEX,
    "QueryText": kendra_query,
    "PageSize": 5,
}

# query_output = kendra_client.query(**kendra_kwargs)
retrieve_output = kendra_client.retrieve(**kendra_kwargs)
```